# Getting handles of multiple selected blocks in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Is there's any way to get handles of all selected block using simulink APIs ?

Suppose I select few blocks using mouse, how could I get handles of all selected blocks in form of an array or cells using simulink APIs ?

With `gcbh` it just gives the handle of recently selected block only.

Basically I want to auto-generate corresponding "From" blocks of all selected "Goto" Blocks and vice-versa.

<sub>Matlab Version : 2010b</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but if you want to auto-generate "From" blocks, I suggest the following from the File Exchange:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40117-autofromtag

I have used it before and it works very well.

Answer (score 6):

This gives you the names of all the selected blocks:

```
blockNames = find_system('Type', 'Block', 'Selected', 'on')
```

You should be able to obtain the handle to the blocks by iterating over the cell array and calling `get_param(blockName, 'handle')`:

```
for i = 1:length(blockNames)
    blockHandles(i)= get_param(blockNames{i},'handle');
end
```

Comment: Okay so I opened a model, selected some blocks, ran the above command and I got an empty matrix :S
`>> find_system('Type', 'Block', 'Selected', 'on') ans = Empty cell array: 0-by-1`

Comment: Seems to be an issue with 2010b then, it works for me on 2013a.

Comment: sad, I've my project on Matlab 2010b :(

Comment: +1. Works for me on R2012b. Case of `'Selected'` didn't matter, but `'on'` must be lower-case.

Comment: Also note that if you only want the selected blocks of the currently active system then you need to use `find_system(gcs(), 'Type', ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a masked subsystem, ensure you have `'LookUnderMasks'` set to `'all'`:

```
find_system(gcs, ...
    'SearchDepth'   , 1,...
    'LookUnderMasks', 'all', ...
    'selected'      , 'on');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the function 'gsb' for get selected blocks. Matlab doesn't seem to have any documentation on this function, I'm not sure why and I'm not sure when it got introduced. The function 'find_system' will probably have more capabilities in terms of what you can filter but 'gsb' is good for simple retrieve selected block tasks.

The function comment is described below.

```
%   GSB(SYS) returns handles to all selected blocks in system
%      SYS and its children.  If omitted, SYS defaults to the
%      current Simulink model (found using GCS).
%   GSB(SYS,DEPTH) constrains the search to the specified integer depth;
%      DEPTH=1 returns only those handles in the current system, and
%      none of its child systems.  If omitted, DEPTH=inf.
%   GSB(0) returns handles to all selected blocks in the root
%      of the current system.
%
%  Example:
%      % Return all selected blocks in
%      % current system and its children:
%      gsb
%
%      % Return selected blocks in current system only:
%      gsb(gcs,1) 
%
%  See also GCS, GCB, GSL.`
```